# Check same word on each array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to check that a string contains the same word when comparing 2 different array's. If there is the same word on each array it will show how many on each inside multidimensional array

Array one is common array type and array two is multidimensional array

**Array 1**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => royalty
    [1] => free
    [2] => picture
)
```

**Array 2**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Affordable and search from millions of royalty free picture
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => from millions of royalty picture
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Provides free picture upload and hosting
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Post your picture here Get permanent links
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Choose your own unique username to access image
        )

)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

)
```

From the above example, array contain each word of **royalty free picture** will show how many word the same in each inside multidimensional array

I was trying it using **strcasecmp()** but it just give me 0 results if two string contains same word and I think it can't give right result for string with so many words.

Comment: @splash58 it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split string and find intersection with the array of seached  words

```
foreach($array2 as &$item)
   $item[0] = count(array_intersect($array1, explode(' ', $item[0])));
```

Comment: @splash58 Can i ask more questions? How if i want to check if there is contains 2 or more string inside one array?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to loop through Array 2 and compare each word to the string with [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Something like this (incomplete):

```
foreach($array2 as $sentence){
    foreach($array1 as $word){
        if(strstr($word, $sentence) !== false){
            $wordsFound++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ha ha ha  :):). but you answer not fully satisfied to OP's desired output